# Not understanding median of medians algorithm to find k-th element

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, median-of-medians

Below is my code for trying to understand the median of medians algorithm (using blocks of size 5). I understand how to get medians of the input, but I'm not sure how to code the block to keep recursing the input until I just have the median. Then after getting that median, I'm not sure how to use it as a pivot to throw away the useless information to partition the input. `getMediansArray` returns an array of size ceil(input.length/5) and `getMedians` just returns the median from an array (only used on arrays of length <= 5).

```java
public static int[] findKthElement(int[] input, int k) {
    int numOfMedians = (int) Math.ceil(input.length/5.0);
    int[] medians = new int[numOfMedians];
    medians = getMediansArray(input, medians)

    // (1) This only gets the first iteration of medians of the
    // input. How do I recurse on this until I just have one median?

    // (2) how should I partition about the pivot once I get it?
}

public static int[] getMediansArray(int[] input, int[] medians) {
    int numOfMedians = (int) Math.ceil(input.length/5.0);
    int[] five = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMedians; i++) {
        if (i != numOfMedians - 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                five[j] = input[(i*5)+j];
            }
            medians[i] = getMedian(five);
        } else {
            int numOfRemainders = input.length % 5;
            int[] remainder = new int[numOfRemainders];
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfRemainders; j++) {
                remainder[j] = input[(i*5)+j];
            }
            medians[i] = getMedian(five);
        }
    }
    return medians;
}

public static int getMedian(int[] input) {
    Arrays.sort(input);
    if (input.length % 2 == 0) {
        return (input[input.length/2] + input[input.length/2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
    return input[input.length/2];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Median of medians is basically just the quick-select algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) improved. While quick-select has O(n) average time complexity, it can slow down to O(n^2) for tricky input.

What you do after finding a median of medians is nothing but an iteration of quick-select algorithm. Median of medians has a nice property that it will be always larger than 30% of elements and smaller than 30% of elements. This guarantees that quick-select using median of medians for a pivot will run in worst time complexity of O(n). Refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

I suggest you start by implementing quick-select. Once you do that, you can use code you already have to select pivot in each step of quick-select.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly ([refreshing my memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)) Median of Medians selects an *approximate* median.  I'm not understanding how it can be used to select the k-th element.

Comment: The title asks for the kth element and the question asks for the exact median.  I'd like to imagine that my feedback is constructive (albeit not as informative as the url I linked to).